# .XZ file with swift on apple tv

Tags: swift, zip, compression, apple-tv, xz

i like to decompress an .xz file format in my xcode project. Has this already implemented one?

i used so until now GzipSwift

```
Alamofire.request("http:.../file.xz", parameters: nil) //Alamofire defaults to GET requests
    .response { response in
        if let data = response.data {
            let decompressedData: Data
            if data.isGzipped {
                decompressedData = try! data.gunzipped()
            } else {
                decompressedData = data
            }                                       
        }
}
```

Comment: Write a swift wrapper for https://tukaani.org/xz/ and you should be able to decompress .xz files

Answer (score 0):

i used successful the [SWCompression](https://github.com/tsolomko/SWCompression) framework

```
import SWCompression
```

...

```
do {
   decompressedData = try XZArchive.unarchive(archive: data)
} catch let _error as XZError {
   print("decompressed Data XZ error " + _error.localizedDescription)
} catch let _error {
   print("Data error " + _error.localizedDescription)
}
```